# Are these two topologies equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Assume $\tau^\prime$ is some topology on $X$. Let $\{T_\alpha\}$ be the set of all topologies on $X$ that strictly contain $\tau^\prime$. Is $\tau^\prime=\bigcap\tau_\alpha$? I can come up with a counter example if $X$ is finite, but not for an infinite set.

Comment: What's your reasoning for when X is finite?

Comment: Assume $X=\{a,b\}$. Let $\tau^\prime=\{\emptyset,X,\{a\}\}$ The only topology that properly contains $\tau^\prime$ is the $X$ itself, and clearly $\tau^\prime$ does not equal $X$. @SeanNemetz

Comment: OP, in your comment, I assume by "X itself" you mean the trivial topology $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, X\}$. But $ \mathcal{T} \subset \tau$ and not $\tau \subset \mathcal{T}$, no? Or did you mean by "X itself" the topology $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\},X\}$?

Answer (score 1):

@Sean Nemetz gave a proposed counterexample in a comment, but then deleted the comment.

Here's a revised version of his idea . . .

Let $X$ be any infinite set, and let $a$ in $X$.

By Zorn's lemma, there is a topology $\tau^\prime$ on $X$ which is maximal among those for which all singletons except $\{a\}$ are open.

But there is only one topology on $X$ which properly contains  $\tau^\prime$, namely the discrete topology on $X$.

Thus, $\tau^\prime$ yields a counterexample.